# A setState on a component causes an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have my `App.js` that cause an infinite loop:

```
function App() {
  const [sessionUuid, setSessionUuid] = useState('')

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header setSessionUuid={setSessionUuid}/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/wine" element={<Wine sessionUuid={sessionUuid} />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `Header` component presents a `login` or a `logout` button, depending if a user is logged on. Only if the user do a login or a logout, the component trigger the `setSessionUuid` function.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (user !== '')
            setSessionUuid(user.sessionUuid)
        else
            setSessionUuid('')
    }, [user, setSessionUuid])
```

This causes an infinite rendering on the `App` component.

I found this workaround on stackoverflow, Wrap the setSessionUuid function in a `wrapperSetParentState = useCallback` function, and pass the `wrapperSetParentState` to the login component. but it doesn't solve the problem, and the infinite rendering remained

```
  const wrapperSetParentState = useCallback(val => {
    setSessionUuid(val);
  }, [setSessionUuid]);
```

What I want to achieve, is that only the component on the route `wine` will be rendered differently depending on the value of `sessionUuid`

Comment: you meant a rendering would take infinitely long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has been a nightmare, but I solved it and I want to share with everyone involved where the error was.

First of all, I create a sandbox that you can visit at `https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-water-jsblw?file=/src/App.js:367-374`: as you can see, it run like a charme ;-) There is no need for strange things, useEffects or other unnecessary stuffs.

So, the error couldn't be there.

Then, I removed the only thing that was in **my** `App.js` and not in the sandbox. I didn't insert it in the initial message because .... it was there for months without problems and was quite invisible for me: **Could any invisible thing create a problem? YES, IT CAN!**

The instruction was

```
const langs = navigator.languages;  //["en-US", "zh-CN", "ja-JP"] 
const userLanguageCode = langs[0].length > 2 ? langs[0].substring(0, 2) : langs;
i18n.changeLanguage(userLanguageCode);
```

And, precisely, it was the `i18n.changeLanguage(userLanguageCode);` that created the problem. I deleted it and everything runs perfectly, as in the sandbox.

Thanks to everybody for the support, and I hope that this misadventure will offer food for thought for everyone.

Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

the `setSeesionUuid` is causing the useEffect to loop forever.
You can remove it from the dependencies array.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (user !== '')
            setSessionUuid(user.sessionUuid)
        else
            setSessionUuid('')
    }, [user])
```

add `//eslint-disable-next-line` if eslint is giving you a warning.

- setSessionUuid shouldn't change and cause the effect to run again but from my experience with a recent project the setState function can be omitted from the useEffect Deps array. user is needed in the dependencies because it could change and be a different value.

Comment: A state setter is guaranteed to be stable (not change it's reference causing useState updates). What's more likely here is that `user` is changing every time the state is updated.

Comment: No, I follow the suggestions from J. Cutshall, but it doesn't change

Comment: - Well with my use of the custom usePrevious hook eslint will want me to include the setter as a dep and it will cause an infinite loop. The Setter should not even be required as a Dep it won't change. But it will cause the effect to run again if it is included. You are right. Something must be incorrect with my usePrevious hook.

Comment: @PaoloDiPietro Then user must be updating constantly.